# Android layout hidden on keyboard show

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I have a strange problem with my layout. When i tap on `EditText`, keyboard is shown but my `EditText` stay *on bottom*, when I tap on back *to hide keyboard*, keyboard hides and `EditText` go up where it should be when i want to input text. When I tap again, keyboard is shown and `EditText` goes down behind the keyboard...

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >
     <ScrollView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:above="@+id/rl_commands">
          <TextView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent
          android:layout_height="24dp"
          android:id="@+id/rl_commands"
          android:alignParentBottom="true">
          <EditText
            ............/>
          <Button
           .........../>
 </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also in `manifest.xml` I added `adjustResize` but problem stays.... What i want is that when I tap(focus) `EditText` and keyboard shows, `RelativeLayout` go up to see what I am typing. And after keyboard hide to resize `RelativeLayout` again and `RelativeLayout` go to bottom of screen. Like in viber...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line in activity tag inside manifest.xml file

> ```
> android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustPan
> ```

for more you can refer :[Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Answer (score 2):

Please try with this line in your `manifest.xml` file:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustPan|adjustResize
```