# Android how to resize activity when keyboard is up

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCreditOnly"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="#28a745"
        android:text="AAAAAA"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCreditOnly2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="#28a745"
        android:text="AAAAAA"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonCreditOnly"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCreditOnly3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40sp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="#28a745"
        android:text="AAAAAA"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonCreditOnly2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonCreditOnly3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and on the manifest I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`. However, when keyboard comes up, some parts of the screen gets hidden.

**I do not want to use a scrollview**, I want all of this to be visible when keyboard is shown. I know that since I have sizes to by buttons and other widgets, they'll always render based on that size, no matter what, so that's why most of them gets outside of the screen. But there's no way of giving a size that is a percentage of the activity, we can only give sizes relative to screen size.

**How to make entire activity fit the screen when keyboard is up?**

**PS**: I followed things like [Android layout hidden on keyboard show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299919/android-layout-hidden-on-keyboard-show) but they only go as far as showing how to put the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` option but not how to resize objects

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add scrollview.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya scrollview will not make things resize, it'll only scroll to the text field I want to use

Comment: Maybe try to detect when the keyboard is hidden/shown and show/hide buttons or other views on that event?

Comment: @MariuszBrona I've searched and it seems detecting keyboard shown/hidden is not trivial